# How can I add one hour to a datetime-local with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, datetime-format

I have this input `<input type="datetime-local" id="myTime" />` in my HTML code. I am using javascript to take the value of this input `var myTime = document.getElementById("myTime").value;` but I need to add one hour to the value and save it in another variable. The format of the datetime is "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS".

I know it seems very easy but I have tried many ways and I just can't get it right. I would appreciate a little help with this one.

Thanks!

Comment: You are actually asking 3 questions: how to parse a timestamp to a Date, how to add an hour, then how to format a string to save elsewhere. Hence the 3 duplicates. There are many questions and answers on each of those topics already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do get value from `myTime` control, then convert it into a new `Date` object, then simply add 1 hour to it.

<sup>*(Click on the button in demo to get the updated date)*</sup>

```js
var myTime = document.getElementById("myTime");
myTime.value = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,16);

function getDatetime() {
  var str = myTime.value;    
  var d = new Date(str);
  console.log('Before:\t', d.toLocaleString())
  
  // Add 1 hour to datetime
  d.setHours(d.getHours() + 1);
  
  console.log('After:\t', d.toLocaleString())
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="myTime" />
<button onclick="getDatetime()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
d = new Date('2020-04-09 10:10:00'); // Converted to UTC Time Zone
console.log(d);
d.setHours(d.getHours() + 1);
console.log(d);

d1 = new Date('2020-04-09 10:10:00'+'+0500'); // Desired Time Zone added.
console.log(d1);
d1.setHours(d1.getHours() + 1);
console.log(d1);

console.log(d.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Australia/Brisbane"}), d.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Shanghai"}), d.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Karachi"})) // Displayed as Time Zone's Date settings.

console.log(d1.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Australia/Brisbane"}), d1.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Shanghai"}), d1.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Karachi"})) // Displayed as Time Zone's Date settings.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this way, try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

DateObj = Date.parse("10/20/2017 16:00");

// vale you get $("#myTime").val(value);

var date = new Date(DateObj+3600000);

    console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US',{ hour12: false }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   for `<input type="datetime-local" id="myTime" />` input field in html put below code in you document ready function or on Change function to get one hour ahead of input time.                                                                  

var today = new Date(document.getElementById("myTime").value);
today.setHours(today.getHours() + 1);
console.log(today)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase yes i added a little. If you found this useful give a upvote. Thanks